# Elasticsearch have duplicate record

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, logstash, serilog

I'm using ELK stack on Bitnami service and using Serilog to send log to Logstash but when I send one log, In kibana I will see two record with different _id a the same message.
[image]

This is my logstash file. One more question, my log model have Id field, this is unique. How can I set it to document_id.

[image]

Comment: You need to share your input and filter configs to help understand what is happening in your pipeline.

Comment: I don't have any filter config.

Comment: And your inputs? How are you receiving the logs? How is the data? You need to provide more information about what are you doing and what you'd expect the result to be.

Comment: I'm using serilog and config it to send log to logstash. The log model is just a simple model with Id field is a Guid.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial: http://blog.romanpavlov.me/logging-serilog-elk/

Comment: Everything work well except the log is duplicated.

Comment: You need to share your full pipeline to help see where is your error, update your question with the full logstash configuration. If you are using the same pipeline of that tutorial then you have a `split` filter, which clones an event based on a field, depending on what you are sending to logstash, this can cause this issue.

Comment: Also make sure that you're not accidentally running two Logstash processes. Maybe you run it once and you didn't properly exit it and it is still running somewhere in the background.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unique id in a field you can use the [document_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id) option on the elasticsearch output with a sprintf reference to the field

```
document_id => "%{Id}"
```

Comment: I tried but may be %{Id} not get my Id Field to the document_id